# if statement does not work with || (or)

Tags: c++, if-statement

i'm new at c++
i was trying to write a program and i found a problem with it
even after i used a simpler program (bellow) i couldn't figure it out

when i input numbers such as 85 or 55, even though program shouldn't respond, it does

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    cin >> a;
    if(a<25 || 30<a<50 || 60<a<75)
    {
        cout << "see it does't work\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please help me

Comment: `30<a<50` -- No. It should be `30 < a && a < 50`.

Comment: You should rewrite your conditions: a < 25 || (30 < a && a < 50) || ...

Comment: Most languages, C++ included, cannot do multi-part inequalities. You have to stick to the form `x < y`, and `||` those statements.

Comment: The binary operators generate boolean results, so `30<a` is either `true` or `false`, comparing either with `50` is always `false` because `false` is converted to 0 and `true` to 1 for an operation with an integer: you need to write ...`30 < a && a < 50`... and ...`60 < a && a < 75`.

Comment: @ajp15243: well, C++ *can* do it if you write a class that wants to, but for the inbuilt types and by default it chooses not to (which means implementing it for your own types is dangerously inconsistent).

Comment: @TonyD Well, it's kind of tiring having to specify "unless you write your own code to do that" after half the statements one makes about programming.

Comment: @ajp15243: there are many languages where it's not possible to overload operators, so the distinction is meaningful if pretty academic

Comment: @TonyD We can go back and forth all we like about it on an academic level (I'm not inclined to disagree with you, anyway), but it's rather beyond this particular question, methinks.

Comment: thank you guys a lot, it was a big help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    cin >> a;
    if(a<25 || (30<a && a<50) || (60<a && a<75))
    {
        cout << "see it does't work\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be this :

```
if(a<25 || (30<a && a<50) || (60<a && a<75))
{
    cout << "see it does't work\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is malformed.

Each expression must evaluate to a true or false, and you cannot do things like upper/lower bounding.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    cin >> a;
    if(a<25 || (a > 30 && a < 50)  || (a> 60 && a <75))
    {
        cout << "see it does't work\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    cin >> a;
    if ((a<25) || ((30<a) && (a<50)) || ((60<a) && (a<75)))
    {
        cout << "see it does't work\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Parenthesis are your friend.
Each binary conditional expression will have a left part (a), operator (<) and right part (25).  You have to break everything down to be expressed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

what is happening in the below if statement is:

```
if(a<25 || 30<a<50 || 60<a<75)
```

when a = 85, 30 is always less than a, and hence true (which means 1 in c++ when converted to integer) and then 1 is always less than 50, hence true.

So, consider changing your if statement to

```
if ( a < 25 || (30 < a && a < 50) || ( 60 < a && a < 75) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no `x < z < y` kind of statement in C++. You should separate those statements into binary parts: `x < z && z < y`.

Let me rewrite that for you:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    std::cin >> a;
    if(a < 25 || (30 < a && a < 50) || (60 < a && a < 75)) {
        std::cout << "See? It does work!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding parenthesis would make reading clearer for those who do not know the precedence of the operators.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, true.